# Mock Generic repository with Generic Unit of Work C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, moq

I have a Generic Repository like this:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{

    private readonly DbContext _context;
    private DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(DbContext context)
    {
      _context = context;
      _dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
       string includeProperties = "")
    {
      IQueryable<TEntity> query = _dbSet;

      if (filter != null)
      {
        query = query.Where(filter);
      }

      foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
          (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
      {
        query = query.Include(includeProperty);
      }

      if (orderBy != null)
      {
        return await orderBy(query).ToListAsync<TEntity>();
      }

      return await query.ToListAsync<TEntity>();
    }
}
```

Generic Unit of Work like this:

```
public class GenericUnitOfWork<TContext> : IUnitOfWork<TContext>, IDisposable where TContext : DbContext
{
    #region Private Member Variables
    private TContext _context = null;

    private Dictionary<Type, object> _repositories = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    public GenericUnitOfWork(TContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Public Properties
    public TContext Context
    {
      get
      {
        return _context;
      }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Public Methods
    public IRepository<TEntity> Repository<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
      if (_repositories.Keys.Contains(typeof(TEntity)))
      {
        return _repositories[typeof(TEntity)] as GenericRepository<TEntity>;
      }

      GenericRepository<TEntity> repo = new GenericRepository<TEntity>(_context);
      _repositories.Add(typeof(TEntity), repo);
      return repo;
    }
}
```

and a UserService:

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{

    private readonly IUnitOfWork<TASConfigDBContext> _unitOfWork;
    private readonly IJwtFactory _jwFactory;
    private readonly ITokenFactory _tokenFactory;



    public UserService(IUnitOfWork<TASConfigDBContext> unitOfWork, IJwtFactory jwtFactory, ITokenFactory tokenfactory)
    {
      _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
      _jwFactory = jwtFactory;
      _tokenFactory = tokenfactory;
    }

    public bool IsUserAuthenticated(string userName, string password)
    {
      var user = _unitOfWork.Repository<Users>().GetQuery().Where(x => string.Equals(x.Name, userName.Trim(), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();

      // ensure we have a user with the given user name
      if (user != null && user.Password == password)
      {
        return true;
      }

      return false;
    }
}
```

The AuthController:

```
public class AuthController : ControllerBase
{
    #region Private Member Variables
    private readonly IUserService _userService;
    private readonly ILogger<AuthController> _logger;
    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="AuthController"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="userService">userService DAL layer.</param>
    /// <param name="logger">nlog logger.</param>
    public AuthController(IUserService userService, ILogger<AuthController> logger)
    {
      _userService = userService;
      _logger = logger;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Public Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns true if login is successful.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Sample login:
    ///
    ///     POST /auth/login
    ///     {
    ///        "Username": "administrator",
    ///        "Password": ""
    ///     }.
    ///
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="login">The username and password.</param>
    /// <returns>returns a token for validated user.</returns>
    /// <response code="200">Success: Returns a token for a validated user.</response>
    /// <response code="400">Bad request.</response>
    /// <response code="401">Unauthorized: username and password doesn't match.</response>
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost("login")]
    [EnableCors("AllowOrigin")]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ResponseMessage), 200)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ResponseMessage), 400)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ResponseMessage), 401)]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromBody] LoginModel login)
    {
      HttpStatusCode statusCode;

      ActionResult response;
      ResponseMessage tokenResponseMessage;
      ResponseToken responseToken;

      if (login == null)
      {
        tokenResponseMessage = new ResponseMessage(false, null, new Message(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest));

        _logger.LogError($"The Login model is null. {(LoginModel)null}");
        response = BadRequest(tokenResponseMessage);
      }
      else if (!ModelState.IsValid)
      {
        var errors = new Hashtable();
        foreach (var pair in ModelState)
        {
          if (pair.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
          {
            errors[pair.Key] = pair.Value.Errors.Select(error => error.ErrorMessage).ToList();
          }
        }

        tokenResponseMessage = new ResponseMessage(false, errors, new Message(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest));
        _logger.LogError($"The ModelState is invalid. {errors} ");

        response = BadRequest(tokenResponseMessage);
      }
      else
      {
        if (_userService.IsUserAuthenticated(login.UserName, login.Password))
        {
          _logger.LogInformation($"Returned with valid username: {login.UserName}");
          responseToken = await _userService.GetResponseToken(login.UserName);

          _logger.LogInformation($"Response token generated for: {login.UserName}");
          statusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;

          tokenResponseMessage = new ResponseMessage(true, responseToken, new Message(statusCode));

          // generate access token
          response = Ok(tokenResponseMessage);
        }
        else
        {
          _logger.LogWarning($"No username for userid : {login.UserName} found");
          statusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
          tokenResponseMessage = new ResponseMessage(false, null, new Message(statusCode, "Incorrect username or password"));

          response = Unauthorized(tokenResponseMessage);
        }
      }

      return response;
    }
```

Now, I am trying to do unit test using Moq:

```
 public async void PostReturnsOkWhenLoginSucceeds()
{

  Mock<IJwtFactory> jwtFactory = new Mock<IJwtFactory>();
  Mock<ITokenFactory> tokenFactory = new Mock<ITokenFactory>();

  _logger = Mock.Of<ILogger<AuthController>>();

  int userId = 13;
  //Arrange
  var user = new Users
  {
    UserId = 13,
    Name = "administrator",
    Password = "test123",
    Active = 1,
    Rights = -1,
    UserGuid = Guid.Parse("7ED0E003-45EF-4C93-B89F-05BF5047F151")
  };

  var userRepositoryMock = new Mock<GenericRepository<Users>>();
  userRepositoryMock.Setup(m => m.GetById(userId)).Returns(user).Verifiable();

  var unitOfWorkMock = new Mock<IUnitOfWork<MyConfigDBContext>>();
  unitOfWorkMock.Setup(m => m.Repository<Users>()).Returns(userRepositoryMock.Object);

  IUserService sut = new UserService(unitOfWorkMock.Object, jwtFactory.Object, tokenFactory.Object);

  _controller = new AuthController(sut, _logger);
  var result = await _controller.Post(new LoginModel("administrator", "test123")).ConfigureAwait(false);

  // assert
  var statusCode = ((ContentResult)result).StatusCode;
  Assert.True(statusCode.HasValue && statusCode.Value == (int)HttpStatusCode.OK);
  }
```

This return Unauthorised instead of Ok. Please suggest as I feel repository is empty.

Comment: What do you actually want to test, the `AuthController` or the `UserService`? If it's the `UserService` then why bother with the `AuthController`? If it's the `AuthController` then why not mock the `IUserService` directly? You also setup the `GetById` in the repository mock, yet this won't be called.

Comment: would like to test authcontroller. what changes do you suggest I do.

Comment: Then you should just mock the `IUserService` directly. You could setup the `IsUserAuthenticated` to return true if the correct username and password is given, else false. (If this is for a real application, then I would also suggest redesigning the authentication, as storing passwords is a security risk.)

Comment: can you suggest changes in code as mocking userservice isnt working. like if I mock userservice directly, then how to mock dbcontext, generic repository and generic unit of work.

Comment: @Gauravsa This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Show the actual subject under test so that a proper mock can be arranged to behave as expected. If the controller post method is what is being tested we need to see that method and how it interacts with the mocked dependency

Comment: @Nkosi: I have added code for authcontroller. The controller have a method which I am trying to test

Comment: You can basically remove everything else except the user service, the controller and the test. everything else is just noise for this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mock only the necessary dependencies that would allow the subject under test to be exercised to completion.

For example your test can be simplified to

```
public async Task Post_Should_Return_Ok_WhenLoginSucceeds() {
    //Arrange
    var logger = Mock.Of<ILogger<AuthController>>();

    var user = new Users {
        UserId = 13,
        Name = "administrator",
        Password = "test123",
        Active = 1,
        Rights = -1,
        UserGuid = Guid.Parse("7ED0E003-45EF-4C93-B89F-05BF5047F151")
    };

    var login = new LoginModel(user.Name, user.Password);

    var userService = new Mock<IUserService>();

    userService
        .Setup(_ => _.IsUserAuthenticated(login.UserName, login.Password))
        .Returns(true);

    userService
        .Setup(_ => _.GetResponseToken(login.UserName))
        .ReturnsAsync(user);

    var controller = new AuthController(userService.Object, logger);

    //Act
    var result = await controller.Post(login);

    //Assert
    var statusCode = ((ContentResult)result).StatusCode;
    Assert.True(statusCode.HasValue && statusCode.Value == (int)HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```